# Door opening animation using adobe flash

Tags: flash

HI i googled about this but couldnt get any source which explained how to go about creating a door opening intro in flash for a website.If anyone can guide or give some useful links,it would be appreciated.I'm a novice with flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://board.flashkit.com/board/showpost.php?p=3848997&postcount=3

Also see this collection of door animations http://www.flashkit.com/cgi-bin/movies/search.cgi?query=doors&x=25&y=7.